# Authenticating users with usermeta fields

Tags: authentication

I have a working site where users are logging into using their email/username and password. Every user has a usermeta field with an unique code.

I have to modify the login page in order to let them log into the app using this code. The login form should have just a "Code" field.

The site is also serving as an API. I'm using WP-REST API and JWT Authentication for WP-API for authentication.

I have to modify the authentication process for the website login form and the api endpoint.

Is there some way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok seems like you have a few moving parts here...

1. You want to add a new meta field (unique code) to the user meta for all users
2. You want to modify the default login form by adding an extra field... a unique code field
3. This unique code field should allow the user to login if they have provided the same unique code in the login form

---

1. I'm going to assume you've added this meta, if not, I suggest using **[carbon-fields](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_form/)** to achieve this

   ```
   Container::make( 'user_meta', 'Login Meta' )
   ->add_fields( array(
       Field::make( 'text', 'unique_code', 'Unique Code' ),
   ));
   ```

---

2. To hook into the login form you'll want to make use of the **[login_form](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_form/)** action

   ```
   add_action( 'login_form', function(){
     echo '<input type="text" name="unique_code" placeholder="Enter your unique code here" />';
   });
   ```

---

3. Authenticating with this unique code field

you'll then want to look at the [**authenticate** filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_authenticate/) which you can hook into to force authenticate the user based on this posted "unique_code" field

```
 add_filter( 'authenticate', function( $user, $username, $password ){

      //do the check for the unique_code field here, 
      //which should be available in the $_POST object


     return $user;
  });
```

---

hope this helps, cheers